# ScrollView Makes my background image bigger why?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to make a scroll view that has a nested relativeLayout view. The realative layout has a background image. When the realativeLayout is the only layout the background image is the size I want it to be.

When I add scroll view it makes the image bigger and I am not sure why and what properties I need to set to fix it.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background2"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtApplicationTitle"
                  android:text="My Application"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                  android:textSize="15dp"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtAbout" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtPrivacyHeader"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/PrivacyHeader"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="94dp" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Privacy"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                  android:text="@string/Privacy"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/txtPrivacyHeader"
                  />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

// this is what I get (you can't tell but it is scrollable)

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/eab982b9d1832983d72197488438cb48.png))</sub>

// this how I want the SrcollView to look(this is the exact same code as above just without the ScrollView wrapping it)

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/b57ff76d74b57f7fdc047df57e7d2d41.png))</sub>

See how the top part has all of sudden grown so much.

Comment: In what respects is it making your image bigger...? (width, height, stretch to fit, etc). also have you tried setting scrollview layout_width to wrap_content?

Comment: @ Adam Storm - Height is getting bigger. I say at least 10-15% bigger when I wrap the scrollview around the realative layout. I tried wrap_content and it seems to not do anything.

Comment: @ Adam Storm - I measured and the height what I want it to be(this is without the scroll bar layout wrapping the relative layout) is 71pxs. When I put the scrollView around it it goes to 87pxs

Comment: I would try embedding your RelativeLayout within a linear layout in your ScrollView: aka <ScrollView><LinearLayout><Your_Relative_Layout> YOUR_CODE </Your_Relative_Layout></LinearLayout></ScrollView> It seems to be there is some weird reformatting optimization going on

Comment: @Adamn Storm - I will try that what should the height and width be set too for the Linear?

Comment: @@Adamn Storm - I tried with fill_parent but still the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ScrollView` has its height set to `wrap_content` and your `RelativeLayout` has its height set to `fill_parent`. That means your `ScrollView` is going to expand to the entire view.

Comment: Should it not expand the entire view?  What do you think they should be so I can try it and see. The background image should take up the entire view. It the top part should not be so stretched.

Comment: I changed the code to represent a different view I am working on same problem but even more noticeable. I added some screenshots as well.